# Getting ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use copy data from CSV to Postgres Table using the following command.

```
psql  -c "\COPY team_cweo.bsa_mobile_pre_retention_asset FROM 'part-00199-8372009a-439d-49e0-9efc-141aead78131-c000.csv' CSV HEADER DELIMITER ','
```

The CSV file is the result oft Spark DataFrameWriter. I realized that for some fields there are null values which is represent as **""** in the CSV file. But because of this I am getting the following error :

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY bsa_mobile_pre_retention_asset, line 3, column 6281410000207
```

How should I do so that Postgresql knows that **""** is null values instead of empty string. Or should I do something in the DataFrameWriter so that null values can be represent as something else in the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be good if you could choose a different representation for NULL values, ideally an empty string. At any rate, it cannot contain the escape character (by default `"`). You can then use the `NULL` option of `COPY`, for example `NULL '(null)'` (the default value is the empty string).

If you cannot do that, you could define the column as type `text` and later convert it with

```
ALTER TABLE tab
   ALTER col TYPE double precision USING CAST (nullif(col, '') AS double precision);
```

But that requires that the table gets rewritten, which can take a while.